# It is possible to assign an object to another with a different type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm working with a C++ project and I need to do some assignment code to assign one object to another with a different type like this:

```
MyClass1 o1;
MyClass2 o2;
o2 = o1;
```

Ofc, we can make this work with the help of a copy assignment operator of `MyClass2`: `MyClass2& operator=(const MyClass1&)`.

But this gonna be a very heavy job for me because there has been thousands of classes, which need to do the assignment like `o2 = o1`. I don't want to add a copy assignment operator for each of them one by one...

I'm thinking if there is some other way, such as some TMP method to help me...

I can ensure that `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` have exactly the same data members with the same declaration order (see below). If so, is there some TMP method, which could help me?

```
struct MyClass1 {
    int a;
    char ch;
    std::string msg;
    // some virtual member functions
};

struct MyClass2 {
    int a;
    char ch;
    std::string msg;
    // some virtual member functions
};
```

BTW, you may want to ask why there are such two classes/structs with the same data members. Well, this is about some historical reason, I can't fusion them onto one class/struct.

**UPDATE**

It seems that I didn't make my question clear. I'll make an example here.

```
void doJob(const MyClass1& o1) {}
void func1(MyClass1 o1) {
    doJob(o1);
}
void func2(MyClass2 o2) {
    MyClass o1;
    o1.? = o2.?; // assign each element of o2 to o1.
    doJob(o1);
}
```

Here is the real case. As you see, `o1.? = o2.?` contains multi lines, it depends on how many data members of MyClass1/MyClass2. I'm trying to find some way to avoid this stupid assignment of all data members one by one in the `func2`.

Also, as I said, I have thousands of classes like MyClass1/MyClass2, meaning that these classes have totally different data members.

So for MyClass1 and MyClass2, `o1.? = o2.?` is `o1.a = o2.a; o1.ch = o2.ch; o1.msg = o2.msg;` But for other classes, it may become `o1.f = o2.f; o1.vec = o2.vec;`. That's why I'm thinking I may need some TMP technique...

**UPDATE2**

Alice developed the classes:

```
struct MyClass1 {// data members};
struct MyClass2 {// data members};
// MyClass1 and MyClass2 have exactly the same data members and declaration order
struct MyClass3 {// data members};
struct MyClass4 {// data members};
// MyClass3 and MyClass4 have exactly the same data members and declaration order
...
...
struct MyClass1000 {// data members};
struct MyClass1001 {// data members};
// MyClass1000 and MyClass1001 have exactly the same data members and declaration order
```

I'm developing the functions:

```
void doJob1(const MyClass1& o1) {}
void func1(MyClass1 o1) {
    doJob(o1);
}
void func2(MyClass2 o2) {
    MyClass1 o1;
    o1.? = o2.?; // assign each element of o2 to o1.
    doJob1(o1);
}
...
...
void doJob1000(const MyClass1000& o1) {}
void func1000(MyClass1000 o1) {
    doJob1000(o1);
}
void func1001(MyClass1001 o2) {
    MyClass1000 o1;
    o1.? = o2.?; // assign each element of o2 to o1.
    doJob1000(o1);
}
```

Why did Alice do such a stupid design? For some historical reason...

Why not using `std::memcpy`? Because these classes contain virtual functions.

Comment: Did you try defining a new "common" class. `struct NewClass{...};` and leave the old names as typedefs. `using MyClass1 = NewClass; using MyClass2 = NewClass;` ?

Comment: @alfC Let me re-edit my question again.. Wait...

Comment: @alfC dude, check my re-re-edit :D

Comment: for your particular purpose, you are inflicting yourself pain by using the symbol `=` because `operator=` needs to be a member function, among other reasons (listed in my answer). Use another name, like “convert”, try use Boost.PFR and some macros and hope for the best.

Comment: @alfC Yeah, it seems that Boost.PFR can help me.

Comment: @Yves I could be wrong, but seems like PFR doesn't work well with types with virtual functions. Most of the PFR functions require the type to be aggregate initializable.

Comment: Maybe the better/easier way is to let `doJob1` accept both `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`?

Comment: if one of the two classes has an *implicit* conversion to the other all the functions will work automatically without defining them twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can... but I is not recommended unless the two classes have an exact one to one correspondence and the exact same meaning in the domain of your problem.

Why is not recommended?

1. Because the operation needs to be manually implemented (the compiler cannot help with a `= default` declaration).

```
    auto operator=(MyClass1 const& other) -> MyClass2& {
        std::tie(a, ch, msg) = std::tie(other.a, other.ch, other.msg);
        return *this;
    }
```

2. Because if you defined assignment, you will eventually need to define equality (`==`), and inequality (`!=`) and in both directions. Otherwise the clases will not behave logically.

```
bool operator==(MyClass1 const& mc1, MyClass2 const& mc2) {
    return std::tie(mc1.a, mc1.ch, mc1.msg) == std::tie(mc2.a, mc2.ch, mc2.msg);
}
bool operator==(MyClass2 const& mc2, MyClass1 const& mc1) {
    return std::tie(mc1.a, mc1.ch, mc1.msg) == std::tie(mc2.a, mc2.ch, mc2.msg);
}

bool operator!=(MyClass1 const& mc1, MyClass2 const& mc2) {
    return std::tie(mc1.a, mc1.ch, mc1.msg) != std::tie(mc2.a, mc2.ch, mc2.msg);
}
bool operator!=(MyClass2 const& mc2, MyClass1 const& mc1) {
    return std::tie(mc1.a, mc1.ch, mc1.msg) != std::tie(mc2.a, mc2.ch, mc2.msg);
}
```

3. Because if you define assignment, you will to define a constructor or a conversion from one to the other.

```
    /*explicit?*/ operator MyClass1() const& {return {a, ch, msg};} // need thios
```

4. and a move constructor?

```
    /*explicit?*/ operator MyClass1() && {return {a, ch, std::move(msg)};} // need this
```

5. if one can be ordered the other also, and you will need to define order between the two classes, in both directions

```
// won't even try
// bool operator<
// bool operator<=
// bool operator>
// bool operator>=
// bool operator<
// bool operator<=
// bool operator>
// bool operator>=
```

and for that matter any function that work with one should work with the other, because well, when you assign you are saying that two things are logical equal among other tings.

full code here: https://godbolt.org/z/c8d34eT48

While it seems to be your case (albeit a very suspicious case), as you see, you open a Pandora's box by defining equality between two classes.

Just by calling the "assignment" `convert` instead you save your self a big headache. Don't use `operator=`. My recommended code is to just use another name:

```
    MyClass2& convert(MyClass1 const& from, MyClass2& to) {
        std::tie(to.a, to.ch, to.msg) = std::tie(from.a, from.ch, from.msg);
        return to;
    }
    MyClass2& convert(MyClass1&& from, MyClass2& to) {
        std::tie(to.a, to.ch, to.msg) = std::tie(from.a, from.ch, std::move(from.msg));
        return to;
    }
```

More material: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABkxMSbejZI

Once you understand the drawbacks, `std::tie` can help you (as shown).
Also, if all classes are public and simple, Boost.PFR https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html

Comment: hmm... I think you misunderstood what I need or I didn't make is clear? What I need is simply to assign each data member of one class to another, that's it. Let me re-edit my question.

Comment: I am trying to explain the not so innocent consequences of converting from one type to the other using `operator=`, which is what you asked. Regarding on how to do it once you understand the drawback... `std:tie` is your friend as show.

Comment: Thanks man, I know what you meant. I just re-edit my question. Well, as I said, I don't want to do it one by one because there are thousands of classes like `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`. What I need is some common method to achieve `o1.? = o2.?` for variant classes.

Comment: Perhaps Boost.PFR can help you do it automatically.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna read some docs about Boost.PFR.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct iClass
{
 int a;
 char ch;
 std::string msg;
 // implement iClass == = operator
};

struct MyClass1 : virtual iClass{

// some virtual member functions
};

struct MyClass2 : virtual iClass {
// some virtual member functions
};
```

Should be able to compare by `reintrepret_cast` to `iClass` as well assignment.

Comment: The `virtual` is not necessary and might mess up things. `reinterpret_cast` is not necessary, `static_cast` to `iClass` will work too and it is safer.